# div not centering with margin: auto?

Tags: html, css, web

I've got one fixed div that's 100% screen width, and another one inside it that's set to a width in pixels. For some reason, even though it has `width: auto`, it's aligning left:

http://jsfiddle.net/jv87N

I can't think of any reason that the `margin: 0px auto;` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `fixed` position from `#nav`.

`margin:0 auto` does not work with `absolute/fixed` position.

[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jv87N/1/)

Comment: Weird, I initially tried it without the `fixed`, and it wasn't showing up at all. I must have ended up changing something else that made it show up, and I thought the `fixed` was responsible. Working perfectly, thanks.